# in nested stack navigation & tab navigation the initialRouteName does not work correctly

Tags: react-native, navigator, stack-navigator

i use stacknavigator & tabnavigator and i nested tab and stack

```js
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
```

```js
const StackNav = () => {
  const loginState = useSelector((state: RootState) => {
    if (state.user.user) {
      if (state.user.user?.ban) {
        return 'Ban';
      }
      return 'LogIn';
    } else {
      return 'LogOut';
    }
  });

  if (loginState === 'Ban') {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Ban">
        <Stack.Screen name="WebView" component={WebView} />
        <Stack.Group screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Ban" component={Ban} />
        </Stack.Group>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  } else if (loginState === 'LogIn') {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="TabNav">
        <Stack.Screen name="WebView" component={WebView} />
        <Stack.Group screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="TabNav" component={TabNav} />
        </Stack.Group>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  } else if (loginState === 'LogOut') {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="VideoScreen">
        <Stack.Screen name="WebView" component={WebView} />
        {/* login step*/}
        <Stack.Group screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="VideoScreen" component={VideoScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="AuthenticationPhoneNumber"
            component={AuthenticationPhoneNumber}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="VerificationCode" component={VerificationCode} />
        </Stack.Group>
        {/* sign up step */}
        <Stack.Group screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="TermsOfService"
            component={TermsOfService}
            options={{gestureEnabled: false}}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="Nickname" component={Nickname} />
          <Stack.Screen name="BirthDate" component={BirthDate} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Gender" component={Gender} />
          <Stack.Screen name="ProfileImage" component={ProfileImage} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Interest" component={Interest} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Region" component={Region} />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Complete"
            component={Complete}
            options={{gestureEnabled: false}}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="Withdraw" component={Withdraw} />
        </Stack.Group>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }
};
```

```js
const TabNav = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      backBehavior="none"
      initialRouteName="HomeTab"
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false, tabBarStyle: styles.tabBar}}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="HomeTab"
        component={HomeTab}
        options={{
          title: '홈',
          tabBarLabelStyle: {
            fontFamily: font.preReg,
            fontSize: 12,
            lineHeight: 12,
            letterSpacing: -0.5,
          },
          tabBarIconStyle: {
            width: 24,
            height: 24,
            flex: 0,
            marginBottom: 4,
          },
          tabBarItemStyle: {
            justifyContent: 'center',
          },
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'rgba(130, 136, 148, 1)',
          tabBarActiveTintColor: 'rgba(49, 53, 61, 1)',
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            const translateY = new Animated.Value(0);
            if (focused) {
              Animated.sequence([
                Animated.timing(translateY, {
                  toValue: -10, // 위로 튀는 애니메이션
                  duration: 100, // 애니메이션 지속 시간 (ms)
                  useNativeDriver: false, // 네이티브 드라이버 사용 여부
                }),
                Animated.timing(translateY, {
                  toValue: 0, // 다시 아래로 튀는 애니메이션
                  duration: 100, // 애니메이션 지속 시간 (ms)
                  useNativeDriver: false, // 네이티브 드라이버 사용 여부
                }),
              ]).start();
            }
            return (
              <View>
                <Animated.View style={{transform: [{translateY}]}}>
                  <Image
                    style={styles.tabIcon}
                    source={
                      focused
                        ? require('../assets/images/ic_home_in.png')
                        : require('../assets/images/ic_home_out.png')
                    }
                  />
                </Animated.View>
              </View>
            );
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="GatheringTab"
        component={GatheringTab}
        options={{
          title: '모임찾기',
          tabBarLabelStyle: {
            fontFamily: font.preReg,
            fontSize: 12,
            lineHeight: 12,
            letterSpacing: -0.5,
          },
          tabBarIconStyle: {
            width: 24,
            height: 24,
            flex: 0,
            marginBottom: 4,
          },
          tabBarItemStyle: {
            justifyContent: 'center',
          },
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'rgba(130, 136, 148, 1)',
          tabBarActiveTintColor: 'rgba(49, 53, 61, 1)',
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            const translateY = new Animated.Value(0);
            if (focused) {
              Animated.sequence([
                Animated.timing(translateY, {
                  toValue: -10, // 위로 튀는 애니메이션
                  duration: 100, // 애니메이션 지속 시간 (ms)
                  useNativeDriver: false, // 네이티브 드라이버 사용 여부
                }),
                Animated.timing(translateY, {
                  toValue: 0, // 다시 아래로 튀는 애니메이션
                  duration: 100, // 애니메이션 지속 시간 (ms)
                  useNativeDriver: false, // 네이티브 드라이버 사용 여부
                }),
              ]).start();
            }
            return (
              <View
                style={
                  {
                    // borderWidth: 1,
                  }
                }>
                <Animated.View style={{transform: [{translateY}]}}>
                  <Image
                    style={styles.tabIcon}
                    source={
                      focused
                        ? require('../assets/images/ic_search_in.png')
                        : require('../assets/images/ic_search_out.png')
                    }
                  />
                </Animated.View>
              </View>
            );
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="FeedTab"
        component={FeedTab}
        options={{
          title: '피드',
          tabBarLabelStyle: {
            fontFamily: font.preReg,
            fontSize: 12,
            lineHeight: 12,
            letterSpacing: -0.5,
          },
          tabBarIconStyle: {
            width: 24,
            height: 24,
            flex: 0,
            marginBottom: 4,
          },
          tabBarItemStyle: {
            justifyContent: 'center',
          },
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'rgba(130, 136, 148, 1)',
          tabBarActiveTintColor: 'rgba(49, 53, 61, 1)',
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            const translateY = new Animated.Value(0);
            if (focused) {
              Animated.sequence([
                Animated.timing(translateY, {
                  toValue: -10, // 위로 튀는 애니메이션
                  duration: 100, // 애니메이션 지속 시간 (ms)
                  useNativeDriver: false, // 네이티브 드라이버 사용 여부
                }),
                Animated.timing(translateY, {
                  toValue: 0, // 다시 아래로 튀는 애니메이션
                  duration: 100, // 애니메이션 지속 시간 (ms)
                  useNativeDriver: false, // 네이티브 드라이버 사용 여부
                }),
              ]).start();
            }
            return (
              <View>
                <Animated.View style={{transform: [{translateY}]}}>
                  <Image
                    style={styles.tabIcon}
                    source={
                      focused
                        ? require('../assets/images/ic_feed_in.png')
                        : require('../assets/images/ic_feed_out.png')
                    }
                  />
                </Animated.View>
              </View>
            );
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="MoreTab"
        component={MoreTab}
        options={{
          title: '더보기',
          tabBarLabelStyle: {
            fontFamily: font.preReg,
            fontSize: 12,
            lineHeight: 12,
            letterSpacing: -0.5,
          },
          tabBarIconStyle: {
            width: 24,
            height: 24,
            flex: 0,
            marginBottom: 4,
          },
          tabBarItemStyle: {
            justifyContent: 'center',
          },
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'rgba(130, 136, 148, 1)',
          tabBarActiveTintColor: 'rgba(49, 53, 61, 1)',
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            const translateY = new Animated.Value(0);
            if (focused) {
              Animated.sequence([
                Animated.timing(translateY, {
                  toValue: -10, // 위로 튀는 애니메이션
                  duration: 100, // 애니메이션 지속 시간 (ms)
                  useNativeDriver: false, // 네이티브 드라이버 사용 여부
                }),
                Animated.timing(translateY, {
                  toValue: 0, // 다시 아래로 튀는 애니메이션
                  duration: 100, // 애니메이션 지속 시간 (ms)
                  useNativeDriver: false, // 네이티브 드라이버 사용 여부
                }),
              ]).start();
            }
            return (
              <View>
                <Animated.View style={{transform: [{translateY}]}}>
                  <Image
                    style={styles.tabIcon}
                    source={
                      focused
                        ? require('../assets/images/ic_more_in.png')
                        : require('../assets/images/ic_more_out.png')
                    }
                  />
                </Animated.View>
              </View>
            );
          },
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

but in this case sometimes initialRouteName does not work correctly
when user state === Login , i expect routing to TavNav(HomeTab) but it go To webView

but if i chage the order right this

```js
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="TabNav">
        <Stack.Group screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="TabNav" component={TabNav} />
        </Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen name="WebView" component={WebView} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
```

it works correctly to Tabnav(HomeTab)
how can i solve this problem?

initialRoute works correctly in nested stack & tab navigator

Comment: Does the way you solved it cause another error?